# Flutter doctor is not compatible with my windows 11

Tags: flutter, flutter-doctor

whenever I type in the command 'flutter doctor' on flutter console, a prompt comes up saying 'This app can't run on your PC'. Please Help.

Comment: Please add your pc specs and error that you recieve

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use this command in your IDE :  flutter doctor -v